# Read row number from Excel sheet using OLEDB Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel, oledb

I am using `OLEDB` object to read an Excel file and return data in a datatable. The following Excel sheet has two columns, which imported, but I want to read the Excel row number as well, with my data.

[image]

This is the code I am using to read the Excel file:

```
private DataTable ImportExcel2007(String strFilePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(strFilePath)) return false;
    String strExcelConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
    + "Data Source=" + strFilePath + ";"
    + "Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes'";
    OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(strExcelConn);
    OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
    try
    {
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        //Check if the Sheet Exists
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        //Get the Schema of the WorkBook
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        connExcel.Close();

        //Read Data from Sheet1
        connExcel.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";

        //Range Query
        //cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "A3:B5]";

        da.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        da.Fill(ds);
        connExcel.Close();
        return ds.Table[0];
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        cmdExcel.Dispose();
        connExcel.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I can manage it by incremented number with new column in data table, but can I apply a WHERE clause with a SELECT statement to return data from different row numbers (where applying an incremented row number may fail)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OLEDB doesn't allow you to select based on row number. You can use something like this:

```
int rowNum = 0;
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("RowNum",typeof(Int32));
    rowNum = 1;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        dr["RowNum"] = rowNum++;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this does not help me because a where condition may select a record from different row number of sheet.